# IOS Map Navigation

Tags: ios, maps, mapkit

I have a small app which uses mapkit. I want to implement navigation. But I want to take advantage of the app Maps already in Iphone, give it an origin and destination and tell it to show the route.

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: -1 For not only not even asking a question, really just stating your desire, and not showing any effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, In viewDidLoad

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42.777126,-76.113281);
    MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:coords addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *toLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];


    MKMapItem *currentLocation = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

    [toLocation setName:@"New York"];
    [currentLocation setName:@"San Fransico"];

    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentLocation, toLocation, nil]
                   launchOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil]
                                                             forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey, nil]]];
```